# SQL Server - Calculate the number of hours between two times and break out those hours into three time periods

Tags: sql-server, time

I'm using SQL server 2008 and don't know where to even begin this calculation. I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

I have two columns, StartTime and EndTime. I have three time ranges: morning 12:00 am - 7:59 am, day 8:00 am to 3:59 (or 15:39) pm, and evening 4:00 pm (or 16:00) to 11:59 (or 23:59) pm.

I want to calculate the number of hours between the StartTime and EndTime that belong in each range. For example, for the first row below, there are 11 hours between 6:00 and 17:00, and there are 2 hours in morning, 8 hours in day, and 1 hour in evening. So I want four columns: one for the 11 hours, one each for the morning, day and evening breakout.

```
StartTime               EndTime
2017-10-25 06:00:00.000 2017-10-25 17:00:00.000
2017-10-26 05:30:00.000 2017-10-26 18:00:00.000
2017-10-30 07:00:00.000 2017-10-30 17:30:00.000
2017-11-01 06:00:00.000 2017-11-01 17:30:00.000
2017-10-06 04:00:00.000 2017-10-06 05:00:00.000
2016-04-28 04:00:00.000 2016-04-28 10:00:00.000
2017-06-30 04:00:00.000 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000
2016-01-26 06:30:00.000 2016-01-26 19:00:00.000
2017-08-15 07:00:00.000 2017-08-15 19:30:00.000
2016-01-28 07:00:00.000 2016-01-28 19:30:00.000
```

Desired results, using the first one

```
NbrHours = 11   
MorningHrs  = 2
DayHrs  = 8
EveningHrs = 1
```

Comment: Are your date/time values always on the same day?  And what about the partial hours?  You should show your desired results.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  No, they are not always on the same day.  For partial hours, I would just want the hour rather than the minutes. So I would use the hour to determine the range in which it belongs. I will update to show a portion of desired results. It doesn't matter if it goes into a different day, I just need the three ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this should do the trick for you ...

```
drop table if exists #times;
go

create table #times(
    StartTime datetime ,
    EndTime datetime
);

insert #times values
('2017-10-25 06:00:00.000', '2017-10-25 17:00:00.000'),
('2017-10-26 05:30:00.000', '2017-10-26 18:00:00.000'),
('2017-10-30 07:00:00.000', '2017-10-30 17:30:00.000'),
('2017-11-01 06:00:00.000', '2017-11-01 17:30:00.000'),
('2017-10-06 04:00:00.000', '2017-10-06 05:00:00.000'),
('2016-04-28 04:00:00.000', '2016-04-28 10:00:00.000'),
('2017-06-30 04:00:00.000', '2017-07-01 00:00:00.000'),
('2016-01-26 06:30:00.000', '2016-01-26 19:00:00.000'),
('2017-08-15 07:00:00.000', '2017-08-15 19:30:00.000'),
('2016-01-28 07:00:00.000', '2016-01-28 19:30:00.000')
;

with
    a as (
        select  StartTime ,
                EndTime ,
                datepart(hour, StartTime) as StartHour ,
                datepart(hour, StartTime) + datediff(hour, StartTime, EndTime) as EndHour
        from    #times
    )
select  a.StartTime,
        a.EndTime ,
        StartHour ,
        EndHour ,
        EndHour - StartHour as Total ,
        case when EndHour > 8 then 8 else EndHour end - case when StartHour < 0 then 0 else StartHour end as Morning ,
        case when EndHour > 16 then 16 else EndHour end - case when StartHour < 8 then 8 else StartHour end as Afternoon ,
        case when EndHour > 24 then 24 else EndHour end - case when StartHour < 16 then 16 else StartHour end as Evening
from    a
;
```

[image]